# I wanted to add Stopwatch in a fragment with bottom navigation activity but findviewbyid shows error. How to resolve?

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-studio-3.6

I wanted to add Stopwatch in a fragment with bottom navigation activity but findviewbyid shows error.
I tried View...., and getView() but nothing works. Please tell some solution to the problem.

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.annotation.Nullable;
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment;
import android.os.SystemClock;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Chronometer;

public class StopwatchFragment extends Fragment {

    private StopwatchFragment(){
    }
    private Chronometer chronometer;
    private boolean running;
    private long pauseOffset;

    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable
            Bundle savedInstanceState ){
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_stopwatch, null);
    }

    chronometer = **findViewById**(R.id.cm);
    public void startChronometer(View view){
        if (!running){
            chronometer.setBase(SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() - pauseOffset);
            chronometer.start();
            running = true;
        }
    }

    public void pauseChronometer(View view){
        if (running){
            chronometer.stop();
            pauseOffset = SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() - chronometer.getBase();
            running = false;
        }
    }

    public void resetChronometer(View view){
        chronometer.setBase(SystemClock.elapsedRealtime());
        pauseOffset = 0;
    }
}
```

This is my Java code where findViewById shows invalid method declaration, missing method body etc....
Please Help!

Answer (score 1):

`findViewById` must be declared **inside** the method. In your case, it is out of any declared one.

Declaring that line at the start of `startChronometer` should work:

```
public void startChronometer(View view)
{
    chronometer = **findViewById**(R.id.cm);
    if (!running){
        chronometer.setBase(SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() - pauseOffset);
        chronometer.start();
        running = true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

inside OnCreateView add
View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_stopwatch, null);
chronometer = view.findViewById**(R.id.cm)